# How would I scrape some of the 'title' attributes if there are multiple under the same HTML tree?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the front page of https://nyaa.si/ for torrent names and torrent magnet links. I was successful in getting the magnet links but am having issues with the torrent names. This is due to the HTML structure of where the torrent names are placed. The contents I'm trying to scrape are located in a `<td>` tag (which are table rows) which can be uniquely identified through an attribute, but after that the contents are located in an `<a>` tag under the `<title>` attribute which has no uniquely identifiable attribute I can see. Is there anyway I can scrape this information?

Here is my code:

```
import re, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

nyaa_link = 'https://nyaa.si/'
request = requests.get(nyaa_link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
source = request.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

#GETTING TORRENT NAMES
title = []
rows = soup.findAll("td", colspan="2")
for row in rows:
    title.append(row.content)

#GETTING MAGNET LINKS
magnets = []
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^magnet")}):
    magnets.append(link.get('href'))
print(magnets)
```

Comment: Note that you have a variable ```rows``` referring to ```td``` which are **not** rows but rather table datum. @eliasbenb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figured out the problem and found a solution

The problem was this line: `if 'comment' not in desired_title:`

What that did was it only processed the HTML which didn't contain 'comment'. The issue is the way the HTML structure on the page I was trying to scrape, basically if the torrent had a comment on it it would show up on the HTML structure higher than the title name. So my code would completely skip torrents with comments on them.

Here is a working solution:

```
import re, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

nyaa_link = 'https://nyaa.si/?q=test'
request = requests.get(nyaa_link)
source = request.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

#GETTING TORRENT NAMES
title = []
n = 0
rows = soup.findAll("td", colspan="2")
for row in rows:
    if 'comment' in row.find('a')['title']:
        desired_title = row.findAll('a', title=True)[1].text
        print(desired_title)
        title.append(desired_title)
        n = n+1
    else:
        desired_title = row.find('a')['title']
        title.append(desired_title)
        print(row.find('a')['title'])
        print('\n')
#print(title)

#GETTING MAGNET LINKS
magnets = []
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^magnet")}):
    magnets.append(link.get('href'))
#print(magnets)

#GETTING NUMBER OF MAGNET LINKS AND TITLES
print('Number of rows', len(rows))
print('Number of magnet links', len(magnets))
print('Number of titles', len(title))
print('Number of removed', n)
```

Thank you [CannedScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6023918/cannedscientist) for some of the code needed for the solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to pull the title from the link in the table datum. Since each `<td>` here contains an `<a>`, just call `td.find('a')['title']`

```
import re, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

nyaa_link = 'https://nyaa.si/'
request = requests.get(nyaa_link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
source = request.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

#GETTING TORRENT NAMES
title = []
rows = soup.findAll("td", colspan="2")
for row in rows:
#UPDATED CODE
    desired_title = row.find('a')['title']
    if 'comment' not in desired_title:
        title.append(desired_title)

#GETTING MAGNET LINKS
magnets = []
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^magnet")}):
    magnets.append(link.get('href'))
print(magnets)
```

Comment: This has minimized the problem by a large amount, now the code only outputs the occasional '1 comment' or '2 comments'.

`https://pastebin.com/XNYzJ9ab`

but it doesn't seem to work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you! This worked, I see why [this](https://pastebin.com/XNYzJ9ab) couldn't work, have a great day!

Comment: So after some further inspection I found that the code doesn't extract EVERY link, it extract a little under half of all the torrent names, I used [this](https://pastebin.com/ZFiAgLFF) which outputted that the code only extracted 28 of the 75 torrent names. Any ideas?

Comment: Ignore the last comment I made (which I deleted) the issue is not to do with chinese characters, becuase I was able to scrape some titles with chinese characters